# Getting Error When Starting Node in ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

I first create a vanilla asp.net core 2.0 web site with vs2017. Then, I add node starting by updating startup.cs with these lines:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddNodeServices(options => {
            options.LaunchWithDebugging = true;
            options.DebuggingPort = 9229;
        });
    }
```

I create a view that returns some data and when I run it locally, it works. Here is that code:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> NodeTest([FromServices] INodeServices nodeServices)
    {

        ViewData["ResultFromNode"] = 
            await nodeServices.InvokeAsync<string>("NodeSrc/myNodeModule.js");
        return View(viewName: "NodeTest");

    }
```

My myNodeModule.js is as follows:

```
module.exports = function (callback) {
    var message = 'Hello from Node js script at ' +
        new Date().toString() + ' process.versions ' +
        process.version;
    callback(/* error */ null, message);
};
```

When I run this locally with vs2017 it works.  When I use VSTS and deploy, even after adding a process variable of ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to Development, I still get an error when I try to browse to the page.  The error i below.

My 2 questions are:
  1.  How can I get better errors reported
  2.  How can I get node to run on the server in both debug and production modes.

Error:

```
Error.
An error occurred while processing your request.
Request ID: 0HL87NKEP2GL6:00000002 
Development Mode
Swapping to Development environment will display more detailed information about the error that occurred. 
Development environment should not be enabled in deployed applications, as it can result in sensitive information from exceptions being displayed to end users. For local debugging, development environment can be enabled by setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development, and restarting the application.
```

Comment: The ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable is used for runtime, it doesn't affect the build. Could you reproduce this issue with a new project? Share the detail build and release log on the OneDrive.

Comment: Go to azure portal=>select your web app=>Application settings=>Add ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT with Development value in App settings, then browse your web app and check the detail error.

Comment: Do you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify Copy if newer in Copy to Output Directory of JS file properties (Right click the JS file=>Properties=>Change Copy to Output Directory to Copy if newer).

BTW: it works fine in local without changing Copy to Output directory, it looks for the file in project root path. Did test with [Using Node Services in ASP.NET Core](https://dotnetthoughts.net/using-node-services-in-aspnet-core/) article

Regarding development environment in Azure Web app, you can do it in Application settings of web app:

1. Go to azure portal
2. Select your web app
3. Select Application Settings
4. Add ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT with Development value in App Settings.